# What does カラオケと遊ぶのが大好きです mean?

Tags: meaning, definitions

What does the following sentence mean?

> カラオケと遊ぶのが大好きです

I know that it has to do with karaoke but whether it is playing karaoke or karaoke and playing is the problem which I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

> 「カラオケと遊{あそ}ぶのが大好{だいす}きです。」

would be a very poorly-written sentence if used in a composition.

In informal speech, however, some people do wind up forming sentences like that.  In that sense, it is real-life Japanese.

It would mean:

> "I love karaoke and playing (in general)."

In other words, the speaker is ***listing two things*** that s/he likes doing.  One is specific (karaoke) and the other, non-specific (playing).

We do not say in the first place:

> 「カラオケ**と**遊ぶ」

to refer to an action regarding karaoke.  We would instead say:

> 「カラオケをする」、「カラオケに行{い}く」、「カラオケを歌{うた}う」, etc.

Some might say:

> 「カラオケ**で**遊ぶ」, but not really 「カラオケ**と**遊ぶ」.

Comment: Can it not also be construed as "like the thing of playing karaoke"?. In other words,"I like Karaoke"? What say you sensei?

Comment: @QuistisTrepe If you are saying `I like Karaoke`, you simply say `カラオケが好きだ/です`.  If you are saying `I like the thing of playing karaoke` you have a problem since you don't technically *play* karaoke,  you can play *by means of* karaoke (カラオケで遊ぶ).  You can *sing* karaoke (カラオケを歌う).  I would probably lean towards `カラオケを歌うことが好きだ/です。`